# How can I index an image as a 2-D array (on Android)?

Tags: android, kotlin, image-processing

I'm building a camera app for Android, in Kotlin, using CameraX.  My ImageAnalyzer will do some processing on the images passed from the camera, and I need to be able to process these images as 2-D arrays.

The CameraX demos use this code

```
val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
// Extract image data from callback object
val data = buffer.toByteArray()
val pixels = data.map { it.toInt() and 0xFF }
```

which results in, effectively, the 1-D array `pixels`.  I would prefer to use `Bitmap.getPixel(x, y)` which is perfect.  Unfortunately I don't have a Bitmap and haven't discovered a way to get one.

How can I index the image like a 2-D array?

Comment: If you know dimensions of the image, you can use modulo to calculate indices for rows.

Comment: What about potential interlacing?

Comment: PlaneProxy lets you check pixel stride.

Comment: So I could use something simple like `x * pixelStride + y * rowStride` to get the index?

Comment: Then the inverse is `y = it / rowStride` and `x = (it % rowStride) / pixelStride`?  Is that correct?